# Accessing iPhone native video player that opens instead of HTML5 video

Tags: iphone, video, html, quicktime

Annoyingly, when you have an HTML5 video on an HTML page, loaded inside an UIWebView, it opens the native player to play that video when you finally press the play button.

Is there a way to access that native player so I can either override the aspect ratio or hide the controls?

I tried checking all of the views that were added to my UIWebView, but that didn't get me anywhere.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could intercept the click on video inside your UIWebView and starts the native player pointing it to the video url.
In this way you have full control on the video player.